# Open source Virtual Machine writen in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vm-implementation

I am wondering if anyone knows of any open source virtual machine projects? The language it is in does not matter, I would just really love to see how they work. I have done alot of searching and could't find much. I am guessing due to the complexity. Even if it is not a full blow VM and just has that functionality, I.E a sandbox.

If anyone knows of one that would be great.

EDIT: I should have been more clear, I am looking for an open source Virtual machine like VMWare that is created in a .net language.

Comment: You  mean something like [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) - and more specifically the [mono runtime](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime)?  If you have done a lot of searching without noticing that one it's time to brush up your googleskills :-)

Comment: I think hes talking about VM products, like VMware. I don't know any, but I don't think he was asking about things like mono

Comment: @Jastill I based my comment on the tages he used.  But even then: [xen](http://www.xen.org/) [kvm](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)?  And, why not, [jslinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/), a PC emulator written in JavaScript?  Looks more like very poor googling skills or a different view on the concept of open source - as could be suspected based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190040/open-source-subversion-repository-hosting-apps

Comment: @Jastill I knew I forgot one: [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: FVU, how are those written in .net languages? I think you have poor reading skills.

Comment: Do you mean a VM for the .NET IL? Or an IL JITer? Or do you mean a VM like a script engine written in a .NET language? Or a .NET runtime for such an engine? Question is very ambiguous.

Comment: I mean a virtual machine like VMWare that is written in a .net language.

Comment: @user1632018 Your original question was "I am wondering if anyone knows of any open source virtual machine projects? **The language it is in does not matter**, I would just really love to see how they work." - emphasis mine.  I know of no virtualization projects written to run under .net, but technically a [game console emulator](http://code.google.com/p/bizhawk/) should be pretty close.

Comment: What does "like VMWare" mean? VMWare is a corporation with many products. Do you mean a hypervisor? An x86 emulator? An OS sandbox? A runtime? Tell us what you are trying to do without presupposing that "VMWare" is the answer.

Comment: Dour, the name of the virtual machine is called is known as VMWare, additionally it is the name of the company. Just like Jastill said before me "I think hes talking about VM products, like VMware." Please read through the question and comments before you try and cut me down. Also this might help you understand what I am asking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine  Also to fvu: In the title it says .net. I am sorry if I was unclear in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com) does application virtualization and has a web service you can consume in your own .Net projects. More info on the web service can be found [here](http://www.cameyo.com/sdk/index.html).

You can find a read-only svn checkout of the SDK source code (written in C#) at http://code.google.com/p/cameyo/source/checkout

**EDIT:** the svn URL is http://cameyo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: You hit it right on the head. This is EXACTLY the functionality I wanted to add to my project. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (and closely related [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)).

> Mono is a free and open source project led by Xamarin (formerly by
>   Novell and originally by Ximian) to create an Ecma standard compliant
>   .NET Framework-compatible set of tools including, among others, a C#
>   compiler and a Common Language Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the comments, [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is one open source .Net implementation; there is also [DotGnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/).